# Do I need to upload a JAR to hadoop every time I want to run a job?

Tags: hadoop

So far, I learned that using `yarn jar ....` pushes my MR job to the resource manager and waits for completion. Every time I want to run my MR job again, I have to push the jar again. I would expect the following features in hadoop but couldn't find an explation.

- Can I submit the yarn MR job and not wait for completion? i.e. run it in the background.
- Why do I need to push the jar file everytime? Can't I store it in hadoop and run it later when needed.